# Use Matlab Raspberry PI Support Package function in Simulink as Matlab Function Block

Tags: linux, matlab, raspberry-pi, simulink, raspberry-pi2

I'm new to Matlab and Simulink and I need to get a simulation run on the Raspberry PI. For interaction I use the Raspberry PI Support Package of Matlab. I use the following code to open the connection to the Raspberry PI and read the internal temperature sensor:

```
mypi = raspi('hostname','username','password','port');
temperature = system(mypi,'command_to_read_temperature')
```

If I run this code separately in the Matlab command line everythink works fine but if I try to run it in a Matlab function block in Simulink it gives me back an error:

```
Base class 'matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay' cannot be loaded. 

Function 'raspi.m' (#29.3176.7592), line 102, column 9:
"function obj = raspi(hostname, username, password, port)"
Launch diagnostic report.
Component: MATLAB Function | Category: Coder Error
```

Is there any way to run code with functions for Raspberry PI in a Matlab function block? I tried with S-functions, but it is way to complicated and complex and didn't work out very well.

Comment: The problem seems to manifest itself while creating the `mypi` object in Simulink. Did you try to create the object on the MATLAB workspace, and then just use it directly in Simulink? I think you should have access to MATLAB's workspace variables from there. I know it's not ideal, but maybe a step forward if it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried to use the created object inside the function but there was an error: `undefined function or variable rpi`. I think you can't access the variable inside the function is it possible to pass a variable as parameter to an matlab function?

Answer (score 1):

While I do not understand what exactly causes the error, I can explain why it can't work that way.

The Raspberry support package for MATLAB is designed to use the Raspberry as an IO-Board, having the sensors and actuators available in MATLAB. The application itself runs on your PC. The command `mypi = raspi('hostname','username','password','port');` sets up this connection.

You attempt to do something else, having an application running on the raspberry. For this use case Simulink and the support-package for simulink is the right choice. These blocks support both, simulating the application on your PC using a network connection to access the sensors and actuators or running the application on the raspberry, directly building the IO into your application.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found out that some functions are not supported for running in Simulink either on PC or on Raspberry. So we had to write C code instead of using Matlab functions for Raspberry.